# how to link a single private S3 file in rails for download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I want to provide a link for users to download a non-public file from Amazon S3 in my rails app. This is not a user-uploaded file, just a single file that I've uploaded that anyone who's logged in should be able to download.

I'm getting lost in S3 documentation/parameters/syntax. Like hours lost. Here's the Amazon url to the non-public file: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/physicianneedtool/static/Historical_Payer_Profile.xlsx. The S3_BUCKET, S3_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY and S3_REGION variables already work with my carrierwave setup in the app, so I know they're good.

My current non-working code:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV["S3_REGION"], 
                           access_key_id: ENV["S3_KEY"], 
                           secret_access_key: ENV["S3_SECRET_KEY"])

@file_url = s3.bucket(ENV["S3_BUCKET"])
              .object('Historical_Payer_Profile.xlsx')
              .get(response_target: 'static/Historical_Payer_Profile.xlsx')
```

The error I get is Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey. In rails console, I found that s3.bucket(ENV["S3_BUCKET"]).object('Historical_Payer_Profile.xlsx') returns a seemingly valid S3 object, so it looks like the error is caused by the .get call at the end. What am I doing wrong there? The path specified for response_target is the exact path I get from the copy path button in the S3 console.

Comment: In `.object(file name should be here)` in your case `.object('Historical_Payer_Profile.xlsx')`

Comment: Thanks @AjayBarot. I updated the code (as shown above in the question), and still getting the nosuchkey error. Any ideas? The response target value is the exact string I get when I use the "copy path" function for the file in the s3 console.

Comment: I even replaced the ENV variables with the literal region/key/bucket strings, just to remove any possibility that there's some issue with the ENV variables.

Comment: I figured this out, will probably post an answer to my own question soon. @AjayBarot the key needed to include the full path btw, so it was 'static/Historical_Payer_Profile.xlsx'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Aws::S3::Presigner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Presigner.html), it allows you to create presigned URLs to share/download private files, and you can make this url expire after some time.

```
presigner = Aws::S3::Presigner.new
presigner.presigned_url(
  :get_object,
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
  key: ENV['S3_KEY'],
  expires_in: 1.day.to_i
).to_s
```